# DotNetNuke VS Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, dotnetnuke

I am planning to build a website for courses online, teachers can create their courses and put their exams, students can enroll, view courses and apply for exams ..

I am a bit confused, to build it with DDN or Drupal ? which is easier and more powerful ?
I have no problem with .NET C# or PHP, although I see C# more easy to code with,

what I need to know, which CMS is better for my case ?
Which CMS is more robust & complete ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a free grade book module for DotNetNuke available at http://www.iowacomputergurus.com/free-products/dotnetnuke-modules/dnn-course-gradebook.aspx. It includes source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you are trying to build DotNetNuke will only really give you authentication and basic page creation out of the box. All those other elements will have to be custom coded in .NET.

If you use Drupal 7 you can build majority of that using CCK, Views and workflow without really having to do a ton of programming if you don't want to.

I have been doing DotNetNuke since 2003 and have developed tons of modules for it, including some publicly available at [www.dnnspot.com](http://www.dnnspot.com)

If I was in your shoes I would do Drupal, but I know both pretty well.

ACTUALLY - If 'I' was in your shoes I would do Ruby on Rails now ;) but ... Drupal would work pretty well and you could get alot if not all of this done without slinging much code. Drupal is crazy.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but why Ruby on Rails is a good choice to build a course delivering website ?? I will have to learn a new language then, isn't Drupal better for my case -as it has lots of things ready- ? or I am going to miss great things at Ruby on Rails ? is there out of the box modules to support most of my needs with Ruby on Rails ?? please advice :-)

Comment: You would probably be best off with Drupal.  Ruby on Rails allows you to 100% custom develop a solution effectively. I have been doing PHP for almost 10 years, .NET for 8. I spent a month learning Ruby on Rails and get to my end goal 5 - 20x faster now.      BUT, the learning curve is steep.   But yes, Drupal sounds like a good fit for you.  Also you may consider other Open Source alternatives closer to your end goal. Check out Moodle or Instructure Canvas.  Both Open Source products that have some similarities to what you need.

Comment: @Ryan: There are a ton of more features. With over 75 built-in extensions (including more than 20 of the most common modules to any use case), there are few other CMS options that span horizontally across the majority of use cases out of the box - including and especially this one.  I'd love to speak to you more about this since I know you and your crew build DNN solutions.

Comment: Hey Will, you know I love you and the @DNNcorp :] but I will always use the best tool for the job. Although, that requires me to know .NET, PHP and Ruby hehe.  But 80%+ of the time I use DNN. To do what Samir wants to do in DNN he is going to have to code some custom modules or try and rely on some 3rd party developers attempt at a LMS.  Drupal's CCK/Views is crazy cool, and could take care of his issues and above situation with 0 coding.  DNN's XMOD, Forms and Lists, all -good- yes. But, what he is describing is ripe for some Drupal!

Answer (score 13):

Of course, either platform has its pros and cons. What you're looking at building is essentially a Learning Management System, or LMS.  There are a few existing LMS solutions built specifically for DotNetNuke.  They include [Engage: Campus](http://www.engagesoftware.com/Products/Modules/Engage_Campus.aspx), [NetLearn](http://www.snowcovered.com/Snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=242&PackageID=18056), and [Accord](http://www.snowcovered.com/Snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=242&PackageID=22737).

I would tell you to go with which ever platform offers you the most features for managing this kind of content for the best return on your investment, and offers you the best comfort level.  If you're familiar with .Net and are comfortable in that arena, then stick with DotNetNuke.  Otherwise go with another platform.  However, having nearly 8 years of experience in developing solutions with DotNetNuke, and 13+ overall in developing software solutions (including PHP-based ones), if I have a choice, I always go with DotNetNuke.  (And not just because I am an employee for a year now.)

I find that DotNetNuke has the most stable builds and releases overall. It's security team and features are second to none. It's community and ecosystem is unrivaled. If you're looking for a pre-built solution for any kind of business problem, chances are that the 10,000+ extensions in the [Store](http://www.snowcovered.com/) or [Forge](http://forge.dotnetnuke.com) will get you up and running with less development time and less expense.  The forge has free (open source) extensions, and the median price of a store extension is $89 (LMS's are quite more expensive though).

The eco-system also boasts over 800 known ISV's out there.  So chances are, if you're looking for support, not only is there an official company to provide it and back you up when something goes wrong, there are numerous other options out there in terms of companies that specialize in DotNetNuke.

One last thing on the releases... DotNetNuke has a known roadmap, a frequent release cycle, and an outstanding reputation for backwards compatibility.  Your extensions will continue to work on the platform as you upgrade to take advantage of the latest and greatest features added to the platform, usability updates, bug fixes, and security updates.

As a Sales Engineer at DNN Corp, I hear all kinds of use cases, and I see DotNetNuke used a lot in educational institutions.  They all use it to varying degrees as not only a CMS, but also a LMS, social platform (even in schools), and more.  Most schools are also standardized in some way on the Microsoft stack too, so integration is much more straight-forward using DotNetNuke.

I could go on, but this is as much time as I have to give you an informed response.

Answer (score 0):

DNN is now built on C# but has always been on .NET. I'm in a similar position as I code in PHP and .NET and have used Drupal and have been working on DNN for the last 4 years. I find that Module Development in DNN is wonderful.

i hope that helps.

Comment: Do you mean Module Development is easier in DNN rather than in Drupal ? Do I have to purchase Visual Studio to start working on DNN ?

Isn't it better to have a module built with a group of people in Drupal rather than building my own module in DNN ? thanks

Comment: You can do custom module development for DotNetNuke without visual studio (not recommended as it would be rather difficult) or by using Visual Studio Express (free), or the paid versions of VS as well. You don't need VS to work with DNN though, only if you're going to use it to build custom modules.

Answer (score 0):

Full featured Learning Management Systems (LMS) require substantial development (man decades), especially if you want to support SCORM eLearning content.  Both DNN and Drupal will offer you most of the add on functionality that you will need in addition to the LMS features - the ability to build web pages, rich text editors, etc.

I would evaluate the different the LMS available for each platform and make your choice based on how robust the LMS are.  In addition, evaluate how easily the LMS integrates with add on modules such as forums, wikis, etc. Most of our clients select our LMS without any knowledge of the portal framework beneath it.

Based on these evaluation metrics I am confident that you will find the [Interzoic Accord LMS](http://www.interzoic.com) running on DNN to be a superior choice.
Chris